# Copy SVN code from one TeamForge account to another with all logs

Tags: svn

I have a SVN repository on http://abc.svn.cvsdude.com/ I want to move that to another location http://cde.svn.cloudforge.com/. I do not want to loose logs from previous Repo I want that should  also be copied. Please let me know if there is a possible solution.

Svadmin can be used if have SVN repo hosted on my server but it is on CVSdude Teamforge.

Answer (score 0):

I could not tell from the sites you listed what version of SVN they are using, or whether they support svnrdump dump/load.  This was added in 1.7.  This allows you to do a svnadmin style dump and load without having access to be on the server.  Here is a link that has more information on the commands.

[Repository data migration using svnrdump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate)